# Display All Legend text in SSRS report when legend value is 0(Zero)

Tags: .net, reporting-services, rdlc, ssrs-2012

I am new in SSRS report can any one provide information regarding SSRS Pie chart legend "Display All Legend text in SSRS report when legend value is 0(Zero)"

I set this Expression in Report

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!Delaymonth1_12.Value) = 0, nothing, sum(Fields!Delaymonth1_12.Value))
```

but My report not display all Legend and I use direct value like

```
=Sum(Fields!Delaymonth1_12.Value)
```

then it's Display 0(Zero) value in Report

Please Check Image : 1st Image Display without Legend and 2nd Image display all legend but display 0(zero)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click > Properties on each series on the chart. Then on the legend tab, click the expression button beside the text "Do not show this series in a legend" Then use this expression:

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!Delaymonth1_12.Value) = 0, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks For Replay
I set your condition in my report but still it does not display Legends in my Chart 
I want to Display all legends which has value 0(Zero) or not. all of them.

Comment: and Also I use following condition 
"=IIF(Sum(Fields!Delaymonth1_12.Value) = 0 or Sum(Fields!Delaymonth1_12.Value) <> 0 or Sum(Fields!Delaymonth1_12.Value) = Nothing, False, TRUE)"

Comment: Try =IIF(Len(Sum(Fields!Delaymonth1_12.Value))> 0, TRUE, FALSE). Also try changing the position of true or false

Comment: Or right click the Legend at the chart then properties. under Visibility tab. Put the expression above